# Keeping shape and animation of ball consistance over period of time

Tags: javascript, two.js

I am new to [two.js](http://jonobr1.github.io/two.js/). I am trying some basic experiments with [rubber ball example](http://jonobr1.github.io/two.js/examples/rubber-ball.html) to reposition ball on every second as per random input instead of mouse movement.

So, I have written below code, but it is removing rubber ball effect after some iteration. I don't know what is going wrong.

Second problem, after some iteration, rubber ball is changing its shape from circle to oval kind of shape.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2v93n/ Tried many times, but not working live with jsFiddle.

```
<body>
<script>
      var two = new Two({
        fullscreen: true,
        autostart: true
      }).appendTo(document.body);

      Two.Resoultion = 32;

      var delta = new Two.Vector();
      var mouse = new Two.Vector();
      var drag = 0.1;
      var radius = 25;
      var shadow = two.makeCircle(two.width / 2, two.height / 2, radius);
      var ball = two.makeCircle(two.width / 2, two.height / 2, radius);
      ball.noStroke().fill = 'green';shadow.noStroke().fill = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)';          shadow.scale = 0.85;

    function moveRubberBall() {

      shadow.offset = new Two.Vector(- radius / 2, radius * 2);

      _.each(ball.vertices, function(v) {
        v.origin = new Two.Vector().copy(v);
      });

      mouse.x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 1);
      mouse.y = Math.floor((Math.random() * 600) + 1);
      shadow.offset.x = 5 * radius * (mouse.x - two.width / 2) / two.width;
      shadow.offset.y = 5 * radius * (mouse.y - two.height / 2) / two.height;

      two.bind('update', function() {

        delta.copy(mouse).subSelf(ball.translation);

        _.each(ball.vertices, function(v, i) {

          var dist = v.origin.distanceTo(delta);
          var pct = dist / radius;

          var x = delta.x * pct;
          var y = delta.y * pct;

          var destx = v.origin.x - x;
          var desty = v.origin.y - y;

          v.x += (destx - v.x) * drag;
          v.y += (desty - v.y) * drag;

          shadow.vertices[i].copy(v);

        });
        ball.translation.addSelf(delta);
        shadow.translation.copy(ball.translation);
        shadow.translation.addSelf(shadow.offset);

      });
  }
  var auto_refresh = setInterval("moveRubberBall()", 1000);
</script>
</body>
```

Please help somebody.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is that `two.bind('update'...)` is within `moveRubberBall()`. When you bind to `update` it means this function will be called on `requestAnimationFrame`, effectively 60FPS. When the event is bound every time `moveRubberBall` is called — once a second — it adds **another** callback. So after 5 seconds there will be 5 updates called 60FPS. I updated your fiddle to import two.js correctly and fix this error outlined:

http://jsfiddle.net/2v93n/1/

Comment: Can u tell me what was the problem in importing two.js?

Comment: Ah, yes sorry about that. The issue is that GitHub doesn't allow you to use any of the branches, so you have to use a CDN or other source to import the file. Coincidentally you can use GitHub's `gh-pages`, so I've linked the two.js from there instead of the master branch: `http://jonobr1.github.io/two.js/third-party/two.js`